# access to checkbox in typescript

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, checkbox

I have a form in html like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="addNewBrand(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <label>name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" required ngModel #name="ngModel">

    <label>active:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="active" required ngModel #active="ngModel">

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Save</button>

</form>
```

in ts file:

```
addNewBrand(form:NgForm){
    console.log(form.value.name + ' -  ' + form.value.active);
}
```

but I can't access to checkbox in ts file. What should I do?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? I tried it and it works, the 'save' button is disabled when active is not checked.

Comment: I want to get the value of checkbox, but I can't.

Comment: Is my method incorrect?

Comment: So, you wanna get a true/false value of the checkbox. However, when checkbox not checked, the save button is disabled. Why don't you remove the
    [disabled]="!f.valid"
binding?

Comment: Nooo, my question is, how can I access a checkbox item that defined in an html form, in typescript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
 <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="active" name="Active"> Active
```

and then

```
addNewBrand(createForm: NgForm) {
   console.log(createForm.value.active)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sajeetharan